# Changing a binomial denominator into a mixed expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Why does $\dfrac{k^3-1}{k-1}$ turn into  $k^3 + 1$ when I'm dividing?

The result of that would be $2$ which is the correct answer $k^2 - k + 1 + \dfrac{2}{k - 1}$.

I only see myself getting $k^3 - 1$... what am I missing here?

Comment: You mean when *you* do calculate it, you're getting $k^3 + 1$? If you show us your steps, we might be able to point out the mistake.

Comment: For $k\ne 1$, we have $\frac{k^3-1}{k-1}=k^2+k+1$. Either there is a typo somewhere, or the calculation is not quoted correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mistyped it: If you have: $\dfrac{k^3+1}{k-1}$, then:

$Q = \dfrac{k^3-1+2}{k-1} = \dfrac{k^3-1}{k-1} + \dfrac{2}{k-1} = k^2+k+1 + \dfrac{2}{k-1}$.

But if you keep it as it was then:

$Q = k^2 + k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook I am using to self-study shows $\dfrac{k3 - 1}{k - 1}$. The answer in the textbook walks be through step by step to the answer, and that shows $\dfrac{k3 + 1}{k - 1}$. I think this was a typo in the textbook that confused me. If that is the case, thank you for clarifying.